# uadetector not properly pulling in family for Android webkit

Tags: android, user-agent

There are a couple UA strings that are not getting their family named pulled out correctly; it is coming up as UNKNOWN.  Mainly it is the Android webkit browser that are having the issues:
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; es-es; GT-I9001-ORANGE/I9001BVKPA Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

This seems to have happen since the release of 2013.10 ua-resource jar (giving the added functionality of device category); before this release it was able to pull out the family as Android Browser.  Was wondering if anyone else was experiencing that issue or knew how to get around it.